# Designer view doesn't show up in VS2013

Tags: c#, wpf

I have recently installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop with Update 4.
The build number is: "12.0.31101.00 Update 4" with .NET Framework build number: "4.5.51641"

I have reboot my computer after the installation and I am using Windows 8.1 x64 with the latest updates also.

When i create a Visual C# => WPF Application project, and i try to hit "View Designer" on the item "MainWindows.xaml" or press "Shift+F7" on the code view the designer does not show up.

I have tried everything, but no designer seems to be in this edition or Visual Studio... No menu even tells the name "Designer" anywhere.
I have used 2010/2012 Express and i always used to have the designer.

Did Microsoft remove the designer from express versions now ? :O

Thanks for your help.

Comment: does this happen when you create a new clean wpf application or after you have modified the code?

Comment: Even with a new clean project. No matter the code is modified or not. But i solved the issue (see below). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I just solved my issue.
The ISO i have downloaded was about 2,00 GB, and I noticed it's a little too light to be VS 2013 (even Express).

The ISO I have just downloaded is about 6 GB. Works nicely now!

Download link: www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=44914
Click "Download" then check the ISO file.